# LocationClient Timer in Service with WakeLock

Tags: android, location, android-service, google-play, android-alarms

**Context:** How can I create some sort of Timer/AlarmManger mechanism that allows a LocationClient to connect for two minutes before polling the location. Below I have pasted my attempt to delay for two minutes before polling the location, but it does not appear to work while in Sleep mode.

**Possible Solutions:** I could use an AlarmManager. However this would force me to create a SECOND service, and then make referring to a single LocationClient very complicated. I could also follow this person's approach ([Using Google Play Services LocationClient in background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902098/using-google-play-services-locationclient-in-background-service)), where in the onConnected method, he performs the location polling.

I would love any recommendations regarding what I should look into

In my onStartCommand method...

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");

    wl.acquire();

    //Getting and Posting Location 
    Log.i("localwordservice", "Creating and Connecting mLocationClient");
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mLocationClient.connect();

    Timer theTimer = new Timer();
    theTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(checkIfGooglePlay()) {
                System.out.println("TIMER is now iniating post location");
                getPostLocation();
                System.out.println("wake lock being released!");
                wl.release();
                System.out.println("The Service is being stopped!");
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }, TWO_MINUTES);
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how LocationClient works. Instead, you should wait for two minutes, connect to Location Services, and then get the current location by calling getLastLocation(). Alternatively, you can call requestLocationUpdates() immediately with a duration of 2 minutes, then either close the connection or turn off updates.

Comment: Hi @Joe, I thought LocationClient needs to be defined, told to connect, wait for a period of time to get a decent connection, use that connection via .getLastLocation(), and then disconnected. I very much appreciate your feedback!